# Writing lists containing x,y,z coordinates into a file as 3 columns with a leading atom name

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

I am fairly new to python. I have been trying to write  nested lists which contain several lists which are in the form of x,y,z coordinates to a file one row at a time.

Ex: lists I have are like this
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

what I want to write them is like this:
Say I have a file called ring1.xyz.
If you open it, it should be like.
H 1 2 3
H 4 5 6
H 10 11 12
H 13 14 15

Only the first two lists should be written to the file.

I currently tried this code block, but it is not working.
any lead\solution is appreciated

```
for s in range(3):
    with open("ring_%s.xyz" %s, "w+") as f:
    for k in range(2):
            for j in x[k]:
                f.write('H\n')
                f.write('       ')
                f.write('%s' % j)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```.txt```. There is not such extension as ```xyz```. Please be extension specific.

Comment: That is okay. I figured it out. extension shouldn't be that much of a problem as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def open_file(l,ind):
    with open("ring"+ind+".txt","a+") as f:
        for i in l[:2]:
            f.write("H "+" ".join(i))
        f.write("\n")

x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
open_file(x,1)
open_file(y,2)
```

Comment: @xdrake consider accepting and up-voting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and tell me if it helped:-

```
for s in range(3):
    with open("ring"+s+".xyz") as f:
        for i in range(2):
            f.write("H ")
            for j in x[i]:
                f.write(str(j))
                f.write(" ")
            f.write("\n")
```

Comment: It gave me this error.       
    
`f.write(j).    
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not float`

Comment: Click on the green tick if my answer helped you :)